# C - exec() a file located in another directory

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec

How can I execute a binary file (compilated from a c source) located in another directory with one of the exec() functions?
I'm working with the inotify API, and I want to execute a file located in another directory.
Here's the homework: notify whenever a file has been created; if this file is an executable file, execute it.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE      (sizeof(struct inotify_event))
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN   (1024 * (EVENT_SIZE + 16))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int fd, wd, length = 0;
char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
struct stat sb;

if(argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ./spy dirpath\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if( (fd = inotify_init()) == -1 )
    perror("inotify_init()");
if( (wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, argv[1], IN_CREATE)) == -1 )
    perror("inotify_add_watch");
while(1) {  
    if( (length = read(fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN)) < 0 )
        perror("read()");
    struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buffer;
    if(event->len) {
        if(event->mask & IN_CREATE) {
            if(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                continue;
            else {
                if(access(event->name, X_OK)) {
                    printf("New executable file created\n");                
                    pid_t child;
                        int cstatus;
                        child = fork();
                        if(child > 0) { /* father */
                wait(&cstatus);
                }
    else { /* child */
        chdir(argv[1]);
        /* This time, I try to tell it directly the filename*/
        char *args[2] = { "./helloworld" ,NULL };
        execvp(args[0], args);
        printf("execvp failed\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

            }
        }
    }
}

inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
close(fd);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `exec`?  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I get "execvp failed".

Comment: With chdir(argv[1]), I am in the directory containing the file I want to execute: is it aimless, since I must specify the pathfile in exec()?

Comment: Is `.` on your PATH?  If not, `execvp()` won't find the file in the current directory.  Use `execv()` instead — it pays no attention to `$PATH` and does execute the file in the current directory unless you specify an alternative directory in the path name you pass to it in the first argument.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: perror("execv") ---> "execv(): Permission denied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is:

```
    char *args[0]; args[1] = NULL;
```

You are trampling out of bounds of your array.  Indeed, in standard C, you can't have arrays of dimension 0 at all.  There's a decent chance that the assignment to the (non-existent) `args[1]` damages or overwrites the pointer `event` (though you might expect a core dump rather than just an 'execvp() failed' message).  You need:

```
    char *args[2] = { event->name, NULL };
```

Don't forget to `exit()` after failure to `execvp()` as otherwise you end up with two processes reading data, which gets very confusing.  You should also report errors on 'stderr'; it is the standard stream for reporting errors.

Comment: Even by doing

    char *args[2] = { event->name, NULL };
    execv(args[0], args);

execv fails :(

Comment: Is the file created really executable?  Is the current directory on your `$PATH`?  (There are mixed views on whether it should be, but if it isn't, the newly created file won't be executed unless you use `"./new-name"` with `execvp()`, though it would work fine with `execv()`.)

Comment: I compile a helloworld.c everytime in order to try this program, and with the access() function I'm sure it has execution permissions with the X_OK flag otherwise my program wouldn't continue. I'll try with "./new-name" as you suggested.

Comment: I tried, and it fails anyway.
What do you mean by "is the current directory on your $PATH"?

Comment: What I say.  Is the directory where the file is being created one of the directories listed in the `$PATH` environment variable.  Either explicitly (`/some/where/useful`) or implicitly (`.` is one of the directories on your `$PATH`).  If the directory where the executables are created is not on your PATH when you invoke `execvp()`, the executable in the current directory will not be executed.

Comment: Error check your `chdir()` call too; you don't know which directory you are in if you don't know that it succeeded.

Comment: Also, have you tried printing out the various values, such as the `event->name` string, so that you know precisely what is being executed?

Comment: Yes, printf("New file created: %s\n", event->name) gives "helloworld", the name of the executable; I don't get what you said about chdir() .